# make a button play sound without lag

Tags: xcode

Im making a button play sound, like a button sound effect for example in jely car 3 when you press like a new game button it would have a sound effect like "boop." I have done that but there is heaps of lag on the ios simulator which means there will be more on the iphone HELP TKS!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside ViewDidLoad

```
AVAudioPlayer *pp1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bomb" ofType:@"wav"]] error:nil];
    self.playerBG = pp1;
    [pp1 prepareToPlay];
      [pp1 release];
```

use the below code to play sound where you want

```
[playerBG play];
```

Comment: I know this was asked LONG ago, but this only works IF you know what sound will play. But what do you do if you have many buttons and each button has a different sound? Obviously I do not want to open 30 players if I have a table of sounds 30 long. Is there a suggestion when the list of sounds is long?