# make a button play sound with no lag

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [make a button play sound without lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742255/make-a-button-play-sound-without-lag)

Im making a button play sound, like a button sound effect for example in jely car 3 when you press like a new game button it would have a sound effect like "boop." I have done that but there is heaps of lag on the ios simulator which means there will be more on the iphone HELP TKS!

Comment: Actually your code will run faster on a real iPhone  vs the simulator.

Comment: @user, please do not post the exact same question multiple times.

Comment: @KirkWoll Don't worry, I'm totally over that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out, basically you just connect it to the first responder

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the Audio 101 tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's page.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/259/audio-101-for-iphone-developers-playing-audio-programmatically

The first code sample shows how to play a sound.  Essentially the code is this:

```
NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MySound" ofType:@"caf"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)soundFileURL, &_MySound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_MySound);
```

This is the simplest way to play a sound.  As Ray mentions in his tutorial, there are other options such as OpenAL that promise lower latency.

Comment: i figured it out, basically you just connect it to the first responder

Comment: The missing declaration for `_MySound` is `SystemSoundID _pewPewSound;`